# react stripe checkout not working and refreshing page

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

Everything was working great until last week. Now I am having some issues with react-stripe-checkout (I notice that the last update was 3 years ago so maybe there is something to do with it)

I have already generated my API tokens and already have a back end and front end code talking to each other.

First I create my checkout component:

```
import StripeCheckout from 'react-stripe-checkout'

...
 <StripeCheckout
   stripeKey="{token}"
   token={handleToken}>
 </StripeCheckout>
```

and my handleToken function is:

```
  const handleToken = async (token) => {
    const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3002/checkout`, {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        token,
        product,
        quantity,
        address: user.address,
      })
    })
  }
```

However, There are these warning on the console:

```
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at <URL> was set without the `SameSite` attribute. 
It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. 
You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at <URL> and <URL>.
```

```
react_devtools_backend.js:2273 You’re using the legacy version of Stripe Checkout.

We released a new version of Checkout in April 2019, which supports mobile wallets and other payment methods:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout

Learn how to upgrade to the new version:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration
```

This is what happens in the back-end

```
 const {
        source = {},
        token,
        product,
        quantity,
        address
      } = httpRequest.body
      const { ip, headers } = httpRequest
      source.ip = ip
      source.browser = headers["User-Agent"]
      if (headers["Referer"]) {
        source.referer = headers["Referer"]
      }

      const body = await checkoutAction({ token, product, quantity, address })

      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: {
          message: 'Successfully purchased!',
          ...body
        }
      }
```

The expected behaviour is to be able to purchase a product. However, when I click on the "react-stripe-checkout" component the page refreshes and nothing happens.

Comment: are you setting up cookies in the response from backend ?

Comment: no... should I? I will include back end's source code

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/js/checkout/redirect_to_checkout. Are you using the given method to use redirect checkout action ? Also please upgrade your stripe package version so that you are using latest version there.

Comment: Nop. I am using react-stripe-checkout for that

Comment: @JeffGoes did you find an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning you quoted is where the key lies:

> You’re using the legacy version of Stripe Checkout.
>
> We released a new version of Checkout in April 2019, which supports
> mobile wallets and other payment methods:
> https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout
>
> Learn how to upgrade to the new version:
> https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/migration

This library is evidently using the old legacy version of checkout that is deprecated and not recommended.

You should follow those links to read the docs about the new Checkout.

You can review an example React implementation in [this repository](https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/blob/master/client-and-server/client/react-cra/src/components/Checkout.js#L100-L117).

**Update Mar 13 2020**: looks like the sample got refactored. Link to the same component is now here:
https://github.com/stripe-samples/checkout-one-time-payments/blob/master/client/react-cra/src/components/Checkout.js

Comment: Thanks Nihal - looks like it got refactored. Added the new link.